# What character/series did this person on Heroes of Cosplay cosplay as?

Tags: cosplay

In the fourth episode of *Heroes of Cosplay*, the winners at Anime Matsuri were cosplaying Zeno (or maybe Xeno) Brothers.  When I Google for this all I find is a reference to Zatch Bell.  Whatever they were cosplaying did not look like Zatch Bell.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the winners?

Comment: @kuwaly - I can't find anything on the web and the footage in the show was brief.  There were two opponents with swords and what seemed to be two sidekicks also with swords.  One of the sidekicks had white hair and an eye-patch.

Comment: Are you sure that these weren't two of the characters? http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130427233959/toonami/images/5/5d/Dufort_and_zeno_bell.jpg In Zatch Bell, Zeno is the brother of Zatch. Zeno is the short one with white hair. The only other Zeno Brothers reference I can find is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno_brothers.

Comment: @kuwaly - Thanks for the legwork.  The segment is so short that it's hard to tell that they're cosplaying "The Last Story".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character depicted (from the photo in @Jon-Lin 's answer) is Zael/エルザ from *[The Last Story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Story)* video game, directed by Hironobu Sakaguchi.

[image: Zael/エルザ]

Answer (score 3):

The characters are from the game "The Last Story" for the Wii. It's an RPG made by Hironobu Sakaguchi.

Comment: You should not assume that nobody has heard of the game. I got more then 200 hours put in that game :). Just never happen to see this question pass by. Maybe you should improve your answer a bit though. Try to add a picture of Kanan and Elsa I believe it was. Also a link to the wiki page might be nice.

Comment: It has it's own tag over on http://gaming.stackexchange.com/ so it's not unknown.

Answer (score 2):

According to the label of the episode:

[image]

The character's name is "Bonds" and it's from "Xeno Bros", which doesn't appear to be from any anime or manga. Strangely, google doesn't bring up anything for those search terms. The MC also mentions "vampires" during the performance part of the competition while they did some sword fighting.

Comment: The only thing I can find when I look up "Xeno Bros" on Google is someone who posts videos of themselves playing Halo under that name.

Comment: There is no way you could tell from the episode, but their group/team name is Xeno Bros.  An homage to Xenogears, Xenosaga and Xenoblade and a riff on Super Smash Bros.